# C# Provider (with EF 6) internal expression mismatch with SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.5, entity-framework-6, iqueryable

Using EF 6 on Net4.5

Posted a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/MatthewDavidYoung/b95ae513628aee42f182) showing the internal Expression and the resulting SQL created by the provider.  Notice that the joins on Occasion (from BrandVisited) and BrandInfo (also from BrandVisited) are missing.  Plus the provider has directly connected up BrandVisited to Respondent via RESP_ID.  This is not the intended behavior and yields incorrect SQL.

Any ideas to what is happening behind the scenes?

Running local against SQL Compact but the production target database is SQL Server.

Just to make it clear.  BrandVisited has foreign keys (in the EF model) to Occassion which in turn has a foreign key to Respondent.  There is **NO** framework relationship between BrandVisited and Respondent.  Despite that the provider (both SQL Compact and SQL Server) associate these table on the Respondent unique key (RESP_ID).  How is this even possible?

Comment: Confirmed toggling over to SQL Server (i.e. switching the provider) has no effect, the SQL is still wrong.

Comment: Same results when constructing the query with Linq.